# using multi-CPU platforms with locust

Tags: locust

I am running htop on the same machine where locust is running.  during the tests I have been running this morning, I see one CPU (of 4) hit 100% while the other CPUs are largely idle.  I have also observed up to 8 locust tasks running.  This is not running distributed.  How does locust implement threading and multiprocessing to maximize the available capabilities of the machine?[image]

Comment: see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73804595/459189 for one more option on how to use locust distributed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html

This applies both for running distributed over multiple machines or just multiple cores.

You need one worker process per core in order to fully utilize the machine.

Comment: i see the page says run a worker for each core.  but the page isn't clear how to do that.  I did figure it out though.

Comment: @ChrisHare Ah thanks. I had the same problem. Turns out you run one locust with --master, and some others with --worker.

Comment: I know this post is a bit old, but I just wanted to know if there is any way I can run locust to utilize multiple cores without spinning up `master` and `workers` distributed mode ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this bash script for running locust in distributed mode:

```
echo -e "\nStart LOCUST MASTER\n"
locust -f locust_scenario.py --headless -L $LOG_LEVEL --logfile=$LOG --master-bind-port=$MASTER_PORT \
--master-bind-host=$MASTER_IP -u $COUNT_OF_USERS  --print-stats --master --expect-workers=$cores --host=$SERVER_HOST&
PID_MASTER=$!
echo "LOCAST MASTER PID = $PID_MASTER"
sleep 5

# start SLAVE (clients)
echo -e "\nStart LOCUST SLAVES\n"
PID_SLAVES=( )
for ((i = 1; i <= $cores; i++));do
  locust -f locust_scenario.py --worker --master-host=$MASTER_IP --master-port=$MASTER_PORT -L $LOG_LEVEL --logfile=$LOG &
  PID_SLAVES+=( $! )
done
echo "LOCAST SLAVE PIDs = ${PID_SLAVES[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option to run locust on multiple cores locally is to run locust master and workers with docker and docker-compose file as described here https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-in-docker.html

Simply mount your locustfile.py inside containers and start it using docker compose command. The number of workers can be easily changed using this command:

```bash
docker-compose up --scale worker=4
```